# Get email password from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, email

i am building a wpf application and in my code there is an email sent with email details as username and password.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
smtp.Credentials = basicCredential;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

is ther any way that the application user can get my email account details?
if yes is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: yes it's possible through reflectors @user3719173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they can probably get it by using .Net Reflector like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

You can prevent .Net Reflection though i haven't used it by using **Obfuscators** that'll hide .Net implementation details.

Obfuscator:

`Obfuscation is the process of renaming this meta-data in an Assembly so that it is no longer useful to a hacker but remains usable to the machine for executing the intended operations. It does not modify the actual instructions or mask them from observation by a hacker.`

Here are a list of .Net Obfuscators, research them well and look through the ups and downs of using one.

[List if obfuscators for .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the application user can get your email username and password by decompiling the application with tools such as ILDasm or JustDecompile.  Do not compile them into your WPF application.

Either send emails using the application users own email account or implement a web service the WPF application will interface with to send emails.